# How can i get Marker id via javaScript in Gmap

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, primefaces

When i create Marker in my bean i set each marker an ID.The reason is i want to access them in the client side(javaScript) by referring that ID. So far i couldn't do that because i cant get the id of the marker.How can i do this.This is my code.

```
//in my bean
LatLng coord = new LatLng(36.885233, 30.702323);
Marker m1 = new Marker(coord, "User A");
m1.setId("a");

getSimpleModel().addOverlay(m1);


//in my xhtml

var markers = map.getMap().markers;
for (var i = 0; i &lt; markers.length; i++) {
                var marker = markers[i];
                 //i want to get the id of the marker here 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the id of the elements with this javascript code:

```
map.getMap().markers[i].id
```

Where 'i' is the element position in markers array. However I think this object id is automatically generated by google library, in your case maybe is better set all the Object DATA in bean: markes, polygons, circles, ...  has  'data' attribute, so you can get all the element attributes you want.

**Bean**:

Setting each marker:

```
    (...)
    if(obj != null ){
         marker.setData(obj);
   }
```

Listener method:

```
 public void onMarkerSelect(OverlaySelectEvent event) {
      marker = (Marker) event.getOverlay();
  }
```

**View:**

Nest a listener in your gmap code:

```
 <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{mapBean.onMarkerSelect}" />
```

So in view you can acess the selected element with:

```
#{mapBean.marker.data.id}
```